# Starting expo project failed: ps and grep commands not found

Tags: macos, shell, expo

I tried running my expo project for the first time on a new M1 Pro mac. I obtained the following error logs. For context, I am using the fish shell. What is wrong? Are ps and grep obtained through some package(s)?

```
bananas@MacBook-Pro ~/E/myproject [254]> expo start
WARNING: expo-cli has not yet been tested against Node.js v17.0.1.
If you encounter any issues, please report them to https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
* >=12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
* >=14.0.0 <15.0.0 (Active LTS)
* >=15.0.0 <17.0.0 (Current Release)

Starting project at /Users/williama/Experiments/prpool
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Opening developer tools in the browser...
/bin/sh: ps: command not found
/bin/sh: grep: command not found
/bin/sh: ps: command not found
/bin/sh: grep: command not found
/bin/sh: ps: command not found
/bin/sh: grep: command not found
/bin/sh: ps: command not found
/bin/sh: grep: command not found
/bin/sh: ps: command not found
/bin/sh: grep: command not found
/bin/sh: ps: command not found
/bin/sh: grep: command not found
Error: spawn open ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:475:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Comment: ps and grep are POSIX commands, which should be available on any Mac. Your PATH may not be set correctly. Does `ps` work in `fish`? Does `expo` work in other shells? Maybe try `bash -lc 'expo start'`, or `sh -c 'PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin${PATH:+:}$PATH" expo start'`. If that works, PATH is probably not set properly, either for fish or expo.

Comment: If I do `/bin/bash -lc 'expo start'`, it works! but without the '`/bin/` prefix, it does not work from fish. How do I properly set up PATH?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have my PATH set up properly.

Before, I had

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin"

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I realized that the last line was overwriting my PATH variable and throwing away everything set on the first line, since the I was not using the $PATH reference (notice the dollar sign) on the second definition.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin"
```